# Postfix: Failure sending mail. Connection refused

Tags: linux, email, postfix, docker, smtp

I have Postfix server installed on my Digitalocean droplet along with my ASP.Net WebApi on docker container.

 When I try to send mail from my ASP WebAPI app I get **Connection refused** exception. 
 
 Here is my C# code

```
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("dev.mydomain.net", 25);

        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("postfix_user@dev.mydomain.net", "passwd");
        //smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom, "MyApp");
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailTo));
        mail.Subject = subect;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.Headers.Add("Message-ID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mail);
```

`/var/log/mail.log` doesnt have a single line about the connection attempt therefore I assume my request never reached the postfix server.
 
Here is my postfix config file:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no
#delay_warning_time = 4h
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.mydomain.net/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.mydomain.net/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = dev.mydomain.net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $myhostname
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 172.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 myIpAddres 172.17.0.0/16 172.18.0.0/16
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

I can send email through `echo "body of the email" | mail -s "subject line" myaddress@yahoo.com` that works.
 
I have tried all possible solutions I found on Google, for the pas two days, but none of them worked. So You are my last hope :) 
Please help. Thanks :)

 
EDIT 1
If I do `telnet dev.mydomain.net 25` from another droplet I have, the connection succeds.

Comment: I dont see Here what's the point. if you want to debug the application you wrote, then it's the wrong site. Stackoverflow.com is imho the right way for that. due i dont believe it that's it is a configuration issue

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, the App is fine, I tried it with another SMTP server.

Comment: so do you use localhost as sending server? if yes, ehy do you use then the hostname?

Comment: Yes, it' local. In the digitalocean tutorial they did like that :)

Answer (score 1):

A search for "digitalocean port 25" brings up [likely relevant documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/support/why-is-smtp-blocked/):

> SMTP port 25 is blocked on all Droplets for new accounts to prevent
> spam and other abuses of our platform.

You may want to connect to your mail server through a port or IP that is not affected by the service-wide block on outgoing TCP port 25.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried "telnet dev.mydomain.net 25" from another droplet I have and it succeded. But I'll check it anyway.

Comment: use localhost instead imho

Comment: did you mean "myhostname = localhost"? I just did it, didn't worked out.